# How can I get the IMEI on Lollipop and upper with ADB?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb

I'm trying to get the IMEI with this command "adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo" but is not working. Also I try this: adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 but neither

How can I resolve it?

Comment: The answer is found right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002663/adb-shell-dumpsys-iphonesubinfo-not-working-since-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: [How to get 2nd IMEI number using adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219105/218526)

Answer (score 1):

My final solution for that was to create an Android application that subtracts the IMEI because some version also had the same problem.

Therefore, I make a request with the common way `adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1` else I run the sentences that install the android application `The plugin`, subtract the IMEI then uninstall it