# How to get 2nd IMEI number using adb?

Tags: adb, command-line, imei

I am currently using this command `adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1"` to get IMEI number, but it only returns 1st one.

Does anyone know how I can get the 2nd IMEI number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which code to use with service call depends on Android release. On Android 9 `IPhoneSubInfo` method [1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IPhoneSubInfo.aidl#28) returns first IMEI while methods [3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IPhoneSubInfo.aidl#38) and [4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IPhoneSubInfo.aidl#38) return both IMEIs:

```
~$ service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 1 | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{8} ' | while read hex; do echo -ne "\u${hex:4:4}\u${hex:0:4}"; done; echo
~$ service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 2 | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{8} ' | while read hex; do echo -ne "\u${hex:4:4}\u${hex:0:4}"; done; echo
```

Related: [How to check IMSI/ICCID on MIUI10?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217971/218526)