# How to get 3rd and 4th IMEI number for an android using ADB command?

Tags: applications, adb, imei

I am using service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 1 to get the 2nd IMEI number. I want to get 3rd and 4th number for quad sim phone. How to get that using adb shell command?

Comment: The way you get 1st and 2nd IMEIs: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219105/218526